# round corners for text input in flash

Tags: flash, coding-style, rounded-corners

i im using the text input component in flash as2,but i need text input with round corners, is there a script that can do it? or somthing?
thanks

Comment: What version of flash are you running? CS2,CS3 maybe? Without knowing that I can't tell you what you can do

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to turn off the outlines on your textfield, and just put a graphic of a box with rounded corners underneath it. There's no way to customize the display of the default textfield outlines, if you have them enabled.